# id is assigned to multiple categories how to remove rows so the id only has one category in r

Tags: r

I am using R and need some help. I have a huge dataset where id is assigned to multiple categories. I want to remove rows so id has only one category. Here is the logic: if the id is assigned to only one category in the column "Assigned" do not remove any rows (see id 2) , but when the id is assigned to multiple categories in column "Assigned" remove rows where it has "Banana" unless there are more rows with the "Banana" than remove rows with "Apple" (see id 3). It will be wonderful if I can get the records that I remove in a separate dataframe.

Here is what I have

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4), 
                 Date=c("04-01-2020", "05-01-2020", "06-01-2020", "04-01-2020",
                 "05-01-2020", "04-01-2020", "05-01-2020", "06-01-2020",
                 "05-01-2020", "06-01-20202"),
                 Assigned = c("Apple", "Banana","Apple","Apple", "Apple",
                             "Apple","Banana","Banana", "Apple", "Banana"))
```

Here is what I want

```
df1 <-  data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4), 
                   Date=c("04-01-2020", "06-01-2020", "04-01-2020",
                          "05-01-2020", "05-01-2020", "06-01-2020",
                          "05-01-2020"),
                   Assigned = c("Apple", "Apple","Apple", "Apple",
                                "Banana","Banana", "Apple"))
```

Also, how can I easily get rows where ID has multiple categories (get all the rows except id 2). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `Mode` function and do a group by `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
Mode <- function(x) {
   ux <- unique(x)
   ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
  }

df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    filter(Assigned == Mode(Assigned))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   ID [4]
#     ID Date       Assigned
#  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>   
#1     1 04-01-2020 Apple   
#2     1 06-01-2020 Apple   
#3     2 04-01-2020 Apple   
#4     2 05-01-2020 Apple   
#5     3 05-01-2020 Banana  
#6     3 06-01-2020 Banana  
#7     4 05-01-2020 Apple
```

---

or in a more compact way

```
library(tibble)
df %>%
    # // creates a frequency column based on ID, Assigned
    add_count(ID, Assigned) %>% 
    # // arrange by ID, Assigned
    arrange(ID, Assigned) %>%
    # // grouped by ID
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    # // create a logical vector where the first 'Assigned' value 
    # // with the max frequency
    filter(Assigned == Assigned[which.max(n)])   %>%
    select(-n) 
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   ID [4]
#     ID Date       Assigned
#  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>   
#1     1 04-01-2020 Apple   
#2     1 06-01-2020 Apple   
#3     2 04-01-2020 Apple   
#4     2 05-01-2020 Apple   
#5     3 05-01-2020 Banana  
#6     3 06-01-2020 Banana  
#7     4 05-01-2020 Apple
```

Comment: I used the category as an example, but sadly in my real dataset the one I want to keep when the categories are tied comes after the one that I want to remove alphabetically.

Comment: @Learner just add `arrange` in between to order the 'Assigned' in alphabetic order.  Updated the last block of code

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `split-apply-bind` technique here to get the keepers

```r
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x) {
                 x[x$Assigned == names(which.max(table(x$Assigned))),]
}))
#>     ID       Date Assigned
#> 1.1  1 04-01-2020    Apple
#> 1.3  1 06-01-2020    Apple
#> 2.4  2 04-01-2020    Apple
#> 2.5  2 05-01-2020    Apple
#> 3.7  3 05-01-2020   Banana
#> 3.8  3 06-01-2020   Banana
#> 4    4 05-01-2020    Apple
```

and the rejects:

```r
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x) {
                 x[x$Assigned != names(which.max(table(x$Assigned))),]
               }))
#>   ID        Date Assigned
#> 1  1  05-01-2020   Banana
#> 3  3  04-01-2020    Apple
#> 4  4 06-01-20202   Banana
```

and the indices of rows with more than one category per ID:

```
as.integer(which(do.call(c, lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x) {
     rep(length(table(x$Assigned)) > 1, nrow(x))
 }))))
#> [1]  1  2  3  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: how does this know to keep the rows with Apple when the id has equal rows of Apple and Banana

Comment: @Learner it keeps the first alphabetically when they are tied

Comment: @Learner in that case then instead of `table(x$Assigned)` in the above, use `rev(table(x$Assigned))`